# Visual Studio - Missing header file "Engine.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/230524-c-tile-engine-from-scratch-part-1/

And everything went proberbly (I think), installed SFML correctly and so on.

However I got to the second section of code:

```
#include "Engine.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

Engine::Engine()
{

}

Engine::~Engine()
{

}

bool Engine::Init()
{
    window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "RPG");

    if(!window)
        return false;

    return true;
}

void Engine::RenderFrame()
{

}

void Engine::ProcessInput()
{
    sf::Event evt;
    //Loop through all window events
    while(window->PollEvent(evt))
    {
        if(evt.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window->Close();
    }
}

void Engine::Update()
{

}

void Engine::MainLoop()
{
    //Loop until our window is closed
    while(window->IsOpened())
    {
        ProcessInput();
        Update();
        RenderFrame();
    }
}

void Engine::Go()
{
    if(!Init())
        throw "Could not initialize Engine";

    MainLoop();
}
```

And after writing it (Double checking and by the copy-paste method, I'm still getting the "Error: Can not open  the source file "Engine.h"."

After some search I checked the through the files to see if the VS even had an "Engine.h" header, which resulted it didn't. I'm not sure if it's a link issue, version issue or wrong install.

I'm hoping anyone can enlighten me on what is wrong. I tried searching for quite some time, but without results.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you create the `Engine.h` according to the 1st section of code?

Comment: The content of the file is actually described in the link you provided: "The first thing we want to do is create a class that will represent our actual engine, so add a new header file called "Engine.h" and write the following code in it:"

Comment: Did you not create Engine.h from the 1st code snippet?

Comment: @songyuanyao aha I'm gonna laugh at my own mistake many thanks. I created a Engine.ccp file not a .h.